# Remove the %2F from query string using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do you remove the `%2F` from the query string in the rewritten URL below?

This is my HTACCESS file...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/?retailcentre=test$1%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,NE,R=301,L]
```

Referral URL...

```
http://test.example.com/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=022641ReservedEventCustomerEmail
```

above then redirects to this REWRITTEN URL...

```
http://www.example.com/?retailcentre=test%2F&utm_source=email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=022641ReservedEventCustomerEmail
```

as you can see it adds a `%2F` after the  `retailcentre=test` which needs removing.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}retailcentre=test [QSA,NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: it removes the `%2F` from the URL

Comment: It might be but value of `retailcentre` query parameter has changed totally from question

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, i've now amended answer.

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.